# How to skip a step if a condition is met in a previous step - Stepper | Angular Material

Tags: angular, mat, skip, disable, stepper

How do I skip a step using a true/false condition of a variable present in a few steps back?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a starting point in code.

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to help you but to answer your question- you remember said variable (in the component, a service, sessionStorage, etc).

Comment: To get help, you need to show up some code, or even better an not working stackblitz with the problem isolated, otherwise you just get downvoted and get frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, that was after all so simple!

On the stepper's parent component html, I used a conditional ngIf that checks the value of a property saved on a form!

Comment: Add some code examples, in your question and in your answar

Answer (score -1):

u can use conditional if. This is a possibility.

Comment: Where do i put that "if"? On the parent or on the step itself?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).